# Gradient system: Why does the potential have a minimum?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

Consider the potential
$$
V(x,y,z)=x^4-x^2+xy+y^2+yz+z^2.
$$
and the gradient system
$$
\dot{\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}}=-\text{grad}V(x,y,z).
$$
I already determined the equilibria:
The equilibria are 
$$
O_1=(0,0,0),\qquad O_2=(3z_0,-2z_0,z_0),\qquad (-3z_0,2z_0,-z_0),
$$
where $z_0^2=2/27$.

Now, the aim is to say which kind of stability the equilibria have.

Linearizing in $O_1$, one sees that the characteristic equation has two negative and one positive root, i.e. $O_1$ is a saddle.

Next, one sees that the system is symmatric with respect to $(x,y,z)\to (-x,-y,-z)$. Since the points $O_2$ and $O_3$ are symmetric, they have the same stability type.

Now, there is one conclusion I cannot understand:

> > The potential must have at least one minimum which corresponds to a stable equilibrium. $O_1$ is not stable, so both $O_2$ and $O_3$ are stable.

*Why does the potential $V(x,y,z)$ have at least one minimum and why does this correspond to a stable equilibrium of the system?*

Answer (score 1):

The potential goes to $\infty$ as $x,y,z \to \infty$. Therefore, on a sufficiently large ball, $V$ must attain its minimum somewhere in the interior. This must be a critical point and it cannot be $O_1$. Hence this must happen at $O_2$ or $O_3$, and due to the symmetry, it must happen at both.

Now at a minimum, the Hessean is positive semidefinite, and thus the linearization of your system has all non-positive eigenvalues, implying linear stability (almost). If you compute the linearization, you will see that the eigenvalues are actually all negtaive at $O_2$ and $O_3$, implying nonlinear asymptotic stability.

Comment: And why does the potential no have a local maximum?

Comment: It must have a minimum and due to the symmetry the minimum is attained at two points. And that together with the saddle point exhausts the list of all critical points.

Comment: But *why* does it have to have a minimum? Did not get that yet.

Comment: Pick a sufficiently large $R$ and show that $V \ge 100$ for $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \ge R^2$. Since $V$ is continuous, it attains its max and its min on the closed ball with radius $R$, which is compact. The minimum is $\le 0 = V(O_1)$ and hence it cannot be attained on the boundary of this ball, it must be attained at some point in the interior of the ball. And so on.